# Add a filter to get_comments_link()

Tags: permalinks, comments

I am trying to change the permalink #comment-xy to #customname-xy.
When i change the corefile comment-template.php on line 754 to

```
$link = $link . '#customname-' . $comment->comment_ID;
```

I achieve the desired result.
But of course this is not elegant.

So, i tried to add a filter to my functions.php:

```
/*has no effect*/
function directcommentlink( $link  ) {
    global $post;
    $hash = '#customname';
    return get_permalink( $post->ID ) . $hash;
}
add_filter( 'get_comments_link', 'directcommentlink' );
```

But this filter has no effect. What is wrong with this filter?
Thanks for your interest. theo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifications of the core code are not recommended.

Note that the core `get_comments_link()` function considers two cases of `$hash`:

```
$hash = get_comments_number( $post_id ) ? '#comments' : '#respond';
```

Also note the second input argument is `$post_id`.

Here's your modified example:

```
add_filter( 'get_comments_link', function( $link, $post_id )
{
    $hash = get_comments_number( $post_id ) ? '#mycomments' : '#myrespond';
    return get_permalink( $post_id ) . $hash;

}, 10, 2 );
```

or another approach might be a simple replacement:

```
add_filter( 'get_comments_link', function( $link, $post_id )
{
    return str_replace( 
        ['#comments', '#respond'], 
        ['#mycomments','#myrespond'], 
        $link 
    );

}, 10, 2 );
```

But it sounds like you want to modify the `get_comment_link()` according to your line number reference. Then you should consider the `get_comment_link` filter:

```
add_filter( 'get_comment_link', function( $link, \WP_Comment $comment )
{
    return str_replace( 
        '#comment-', 
        '#mycomment-', 
        $link 
    );

}, 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for your quick response. Your third suggestion works fine. regards theo (sorry, my reputation is low, cannot vote)

Comment: By the way: Birkir Bjarnasson plays in Basel (my home). We had a lot of fun watching the Iceland football team this year.

Comment: Hehe that was quite an adventure ;-) I've enjoyed traveling in Switzerland hopefully I can do that again and even visit Basel ;-) @timholz